# Raycast threejs touch event not working using mouse event

Tags: javascript, three.js

I’ve been working on threejs mouse raycast with fabricjs, and it is working now [here](https://jsfiddle.net/naonvl/3zcugboq/17/show) but the problem is the object didn’t move if i was using smartphone which is using touch. Should i create another event listener for touch event? or should it be working just fine using mouse event?

here's how i can move the object

```
  if (e.target !== this.upperCanvasEl) {
    var positionOnScene = getPositionOnScene(container, e);
    pointer.x = positionOnScene.x;
    pointer.y = positionOnScene.y;
  }
```

and here's `getPositionOnScene` function

```
 function getPositionOnScene(sceneContainer, evt) {
    var array = getMousePosition(container, evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
    onClickPosition.fromArray(array);
    var intersects = getIntersects(onClickPosition, scene.children);
    if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].uv) {
      var uv = intersects[0].uv;
      intersects[0].object.material.map.transformUv(uv);
      return {
        x: getRealPosition('x', uv.x),
        y: getRealPosition('y', uv.y)
      }
    }
    return null
  }
```

can anyone help me? any thought would be really helpful

Comment: Touch devices do not follow the usual mouse events because they don't have a mouse. Instead, you'll have to use the [TouchEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent#touch_event_types), which is very similar to mouse, but accommodates for the differences of touch. So you'll have to do `addEventListener("touchstart", callback)`. It also supports `"touchend" and "touchmove"`.

Comment: hey what do u think about this?https://www.owayo.com/konfigurator_html/index.php?sport=football&product=shirts_f3&lang=en&land=us# does this using touchevent too?

Answer (score 0):

### There is 2 reasons.

##### 1:

#### You return null in the `getPositionOnScene` function.

##### 2:

#### Touch is not the same as a mouse event.

You will have to do `document.addEventListener("mousedown", callback)` 
so it supports mouse events too.

Comment: yeah i thought that too, i also tried pointer event but no luck. so i create a custom handler for touch, also i discovered that fabricjs version 460 is not working on mobile idk y, but i use 4.2 now it's working on mobile.  anyway thanks for the answer